# Forms Django Python

Tags: django, database, forms

Could someone help me?

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I try to change ma value in database but it doesn't work. Still it is the same like it set default.. Below my codes...Thank You in advance.

koszyk.html

```
     {% for produkt in produkty%}
            <div id="bin">

                <div class ='name'>{{ produkt.nazwa }}</div> <div class="product_price">
                {{ produkt.cena }} {{ produkt.ilosc }}

                <form method="POST">

                    {% csrf_token %}

                    {{ form }}
                    <button type="submit" href ="{% url 'numbers' produkt.id %}">zaktualizuj</button>
                </form>
                </div>
                <div class="delete"> <a href="{% url 'usun' produkt.id %}">Usuń</a></div>


        {% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class Basket(models.Model):

    nazwa = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, unique=True, default="")
    cena = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=2000)
    opis = models.TextField(default="")
    ilosc = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=3)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Shop, Basket

class IloscForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Basket
        fields = ['ilosc',]
```

views.py

```
def numbers(request, id):
    form = IloscForm(request.POST or None)
    produkt = Basket.objects.get(pk=id)
    if form.is_valid():
        ilosc = form.save(commit=False)
        produkt.ilosc = ilosc
        ilosc.save()
    return redirect('koszyk')
```

```
def koszyk(request):
    produkty = Basket.objects.all()
    form = IloscForm()
    return render(request, 'koszyk.html', {'produkty': produkty, 'form':form})
```

I would be very grateful for help!

Natalia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not saving the changes to `produkt`. Instead you are saving `ilosc`.

Change

```py
ilosc.save()
```

to

```py
produkt.save()
```

Comment: Thank You a lot it works with one more change.                                                                                                   Thank You !! :)